# How Check if all inputs different from each other by parsley validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, parsley

Sorry I'm a beginner ***
I have 6 School Children id , and the teacher will put this ids or not important but he must put 1 minimum   .. or when he put more of one must them be different from each other .

I used parsley.js to validate  my test live here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mssss/8aq9ebdx/9/)

I tried to check more than 6 inputs if they are different from each other or not Because if the inputs are the same, a message appears on the similar field .. by parsley and jq .
that what I did

```
    <form action="" id="homeform" method="POST" style="width: 100%;"  novalidate="novalidate">
  <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m1" id="m1" />
 <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m2" id="m2" />
 <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m3" id="m3" />
 <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m4" id="m4" />
 <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m5" id="m5" />
 <input type="text" class="datac selector"  data-parsley-date="" name="m6" id="m6" />
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Check Out</button>

 </form>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.ParsleyValidator
    .addValidator(
        'date',
        function(value, requirements) {

    $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
var values = []
$('.selector').each(function(){
if ($(this).val() != ''){
if(!values.includes(this.value)){
 values.push(this.value)
      return true;
         $(this).css("border-color", ""); 
   }else{
    values.push(this.value)
    $(this).css("border-color", "red");
      return false;

}   

}

});
},
        34
    )
    .addMessage('en', 'date', "Enter a valid date");
</script>
```

and there is anyway , I can marge JavaScript with parsley validator  ?

Comment: This does not appear to be a complete example. please include a link to the library you are using and any other add ins. Please also provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner ***
I have 6 School Children id , and the teacher will put this ids or not important but he must put 1 minimum   .. or when he put more of one must them be different from each other .

I used parsley.js to validate  my test live here : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mssss/8aq9ebdx/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the details found here, https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#custom the following example should be of use.

```css
.selector {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.9.2/parsley.js" integrity="sha512-Fq/wHuMI7AraoOK+juE5oYILKvSPe6GC5ZWZnvpOO/ZPdtyA29n+a5kVLP4XaLyDy9D1IBPYzdFycO33Ijd0Pg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<form id="homeform" action="" method="post">
  <p>Enter Dates</p>
  <div data-parsley-check-empty="1">
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m1" id="m1" />
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m2" id="m2" />
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m3" id="m3" />
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m4" id="m4" />
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m5" id="m5" />
    <input type="text" class="datac selector" data-parsley-unique-date="" data-parsley-group="block-1" name="m6" id="m6" />
  </div>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Check Out</button>
</form>
<script>
  window.Parsley.addValidator(
    'uniqueDate', {
      validateString: function(value) {
        var count = 0;
        $(".selector").each(function(i, el) {
          if (value === $(el).val()) {
            count++;
          }
        });
        return (count <= 1);
      },
      messages: {
        en: 'All dates must be Unique.',
      }
    }
  );

  window.Parsley.addValidator(
    'checkEmtpy', {
      messages: {
        en: 'You must fill in at least one of these dates!'
      },
      requirementType: 'integer',
      validate: function(_value, requirement, instance) {
        console.log("Group Validation");
        for (var i = 1; i <= requirement; i++) {
          if (instance.parent.isValid({
              group: 'block-' + i,
              force: true
            })) {
            return true; // One section is filled, this check is valid
          }
        }
        return false; // No section is filled, this validation fails
      }
    });

  var formInstance = $("#homeform").parsley({
      inputs: Parsley.options.inputs + ',[data-parsley-check-empty]'
    })
    .on('form:submit', function() {
      console.log("Submit Event");
      return false; // Don't submit form for this demo
    });
</script>
```

Firstly, your Syntax was incorrect. The `.addValidator()` appears to require s String corresponding to the data attribute and a Object defining the details.

You stated you wanted each field to have a unique value. There should only be one or less of the `value` as the validator inspects each field. We assume a failure and start a count. We then iterate over each field and compare our `value` to the value for each and increase the count if they match. We know it must match at least one of them, the one we're validating. If the `count` is less than or equal to 1, we can return a Valid response.

Comment: I understand you, but I still get an error and the form is not working ... I don't why :( can you please check it here :  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mssss/8aq9ebdx/12/)

Comment: @mssss I just updated the answer. I had to dig through the documents a lot more. I switched it over to a `validateString` and adjusted the selector to be a more unique item.

Comment: @mssss here is a working fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5s1f4aLc/

Comment: I learned a lot from you, thank you very much, How i can  if I want to make sure I have to add value in at least one input ?

Comment: @mssss just add the `required=""` attribute to at least one of the fields.

Comment: if i add required="" that will make this input only required , but if i add value to another input will not working .. are you understand me ? so i must make that in the loop or in the script we did .

Comment: @mssss I do not understand. See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5s1f4aLc/6/ you can see `required=""` is on the first field but not the others. This requires at least that one to be filled in. This means the user cannot submit without filling in that one field. If they fill in others as well, thats okay.

Comment: exp : now the first input will required only but If they fill in others not the first input the form will appear the first input  required . now it clear ? 
i want the user add any input  not must the first input .

Comment: @mssss Ok, to confirm, you want the User to be able to enter a date in at least one field, not the first itself. I think that can be a group requirement. I will check.

Comment: Yes.you are right that what i looking for , that user can fill any input Not a specific one .

Comment: @mssss I reviewed this: https://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html and updated my answer. It does not seem to work, even though it should. The alternative would be to put this type of check in the `form:submit` callback.

Comment: Oh ! that same what happened with me , i found it and I tried to test it .